# Program is not generating random number and I am not sure why

Tags: c

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#define ERROR_CREATE       1
#define ERROR_JOIN         2



// create the function to be executed as a thread
void *thread(void *ptr)
{
    uintptr_t type = (uintptr_t) ptr; // thread number
    srand(time(NULL) + getpid());
    int wait = rand() % 10; // randomizes numbers from 0 to 10
    sleep(wait); // waits in time intervals of seconds
    printf("Thread - %ld waiting for %d seconds\n",type, wait);
    return  ptr; // returns the thread number
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error with command line arguments");
    }

    int num_threads = atoi(argv[1]);
    pthread_t threads[num_threads]; // array of thread types

    for (long i = 1; i <= num_threads; i++) {
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread, (void *)i) != 0)
            // if there's an error creating thread
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Error: could not create thread");
            return ERROR_CREATE;
        }
    }
        // terminate each thread assigned
    for (int i = 1; i <= num_threads; i++) {
        if (pthread_join(threads[i], NULL) != 0)
            // if there's an error ending each thread
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not terminate thread");
            return ERROR_JOIN;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> Seeding the rand function, I am still getting the same number outputted. I understand the hardware is fast and therefore is getting the same answer as the clock speed is faster than seeding the rand function. Does anyone know another way of getting more variety from the rand function?

Comment: Don't call `srand()` in each thread. Call it once in `main()`.

Comment: Is this a [example]? It seems like most of your code doesn't have much to do with random value generation and can be cut out. When asking your question, pretend you're asking a busy colleague to spend some time helping you. Because you are. Anything you can do to make the ask easier on me will get you a better answer, and it will get you that answer faster.

Comment: `getpid()` is the same in all the threads. Use `gettid()` to get the thread ID.

Comment: @Alex Fridman indices in C for arrays start from 0.

Comment: Also note that "[rand() is not guaranteed to be thread-safe](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand)".

Comment: ObDilbert: https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Return if `argv[1]` is not populated otherwise it segfaults.
2. `srand()` resets the sequence.  As you call it multiple times with the same value this is not what you want.  Moved it `main()`.
3. The array `threads` is accessed out of bounds in the two loops.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define ERROR_CREATE       1
#define ERROR_JOIN         2

// create the function to be executed as a thread
void *thread(void *ptr) {
    uintptr_t type = (uintptr_t) ptr; // thread number
    int wait = rand() % 10; // randomizes numbers from 0 to 10
    sleep(wait); // waits in time intervals of seconds
    printf("Thread - %ld waiting for %d seconds\n",type, wait);
    return  ptr; // returns the thread number
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error with command line arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    int num_threads = atoi(argv[1]);
    pthread_t threads[num_threads]; // array of thread types

    for (long i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread, (void *)i) != 0)
            // if there's an error creating thread
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Error: could not create thread");
            return ERROR_CREATE;
        }
    }
    // terminate each thread assigned
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        if (pthread_join(threads[i], NULL) != 0)
            // if there's an error ending each thread
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not terminate thread");
            return ERROR_JOIN;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is a couple of sample runs:

```
$ ./a.out 2
Thread - 1 waiting for 3 seconds
Thread - 2 waiting for 7 seconds
$ ./a.out 2
Thread - 1 waiting for 3 seconds
Thread - 2 waiting for 6 seconds
```